# Как оценить работу и сроки над проектом?

Tags: project

Как оценивать:

- Цену за исполнение работы
- Сроки исполнения

Как рассчитать цену/сроки, которые нужно сказать заказчику? Тем более, если раньше не сталкивался с проектами относительно большого масштаба (раньше работал с более мелкими).

Comment: Как по мне то вопрос следует оставить, но стоит его переформулировать. Любой программист сталкивается с нуждой УМЕТЬ оценивать свою работу и оценивать обьем работы, поэтому считаю что голоса за закрытие лишними.

Comment: @Andrew Да, несомненно вы правы -оценка своей работы и объема работ важно и каждый из нас сталкивается с этим каждый день. Но данный ресурс обсуждает техническую сторону нашей проф. деятельности и не стоит его раздувать на все смежные темы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В сколько долларов в час ты себя оцениваешь?
2. В сколько часов ты оцениваешь обьем работ на проекте?
3. Умножь на коэфициэнт ошибки (1.2-1.5), т.к. с малым опытом сложно обьективно оценить, сколько времени это займет.

Ну а дальше перемножь все эти числа.

По поводу сроков:

1. Оцени количество часов, которые тебе теоретически нужно работать
2. Умножь на 2

И объясни заказчику, что это с запасом, а не точный день сдачи. :)

Comment: Первоначальную оценку трудоемкости в человекомесяцах лучше умножать на 3, а получившиеся в результате умножения на ежемесячную ЗП деньги еще на 5. Вот такие прикидки по стоимости и срокам стоит для начала переговоров выкатывать.

Comment: Разделить всю работу на блоки, оценить сколько времени надо на исполнение каждого блока. Если в каком-то блоке трудозатраты больше 3-5 дней, то разделить его на более мелкие части. Делить до тех пор, пока каждая часть не будет более-менее вменяемого размера (3 дня). Если для каких-то частей требуется изучение или тестирование чего-либо - добавить время. Итоговый результат в часах умножить на 1.5 или даже 2 (как минимум).